# Tradução de "Variadic"?

Tags: tradução-inglês, neologismos

Nas ciências de computação usa-se a palavra [*"aridade"*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aridade) para descrever:

> o número de argumentos ou operandos tomados

Ora em inglês existe a palavra *"variadic"* para denominar um número de argumentos variável.

A pergunta é qual a tradução para português? Vejo 3 hipóteses:

1. Dizemos *"n-ária*" (penso que significa n-argumentos sem implicar ser o número variável).
2. Ou se *"variádica"* (está aqui [um exemplo](http://excript.com/tag/funcao-variadica.html)). O dicionário priberam [não tem o verbete](https://dicionario.priberam.org/variadico).
3. Dizer por extenso: *"de número variável"*. Pois segundo a wikipedia no inglês a palavra *"variadic"* é neologismo:

> [The term variadic is a neologism, dating back to 1936-1937](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)

Comment: Tenho minhas dúvidas que se deveria chamar uma palavra de mais de 80 anos de "neologismo", ainda mais em computação.

Comment: @stafusa podes corrigir a wikipedia, a citação é da lá.

Comment: Sim, eu notei, bad_coder, você também não acha estranho?

Comment: @stafusa tu não achas a pergunta boa para merecer um voto?

Comment: Sim! Vivo esquecendo de votar. Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Variádica*** já é aceite pelo menos nalguns círculos em universidades brasileiras. Encontrei o termo numa dissertação de mestrado e quatro de bacharelato (que ao que descobri equivale à licenciatura de Portugal) — todas aprovadas por bancas examinadoras — e também em três livros, todos traduções do inglês. Indico as referências abaixo. [Este (Flanagan, 2013, p. 168)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=zWNyDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA168&dq=%22fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20vari%C3%A1dicas%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiwhtSTnd_tAhXCh1wKHf08A40Q6AEwAHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20vari%C3%A1dicas%22&f=false) dá mais dois nomes alternativos:

> Funções come essa, que podem aceitar qualquer número de argumentos, são chamadas de *funções variádicas, funções de aridade variável* ou *funções varags*.

Encontra-se já também [*variádica* em espanhol (papers no Google Scholar)](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=10&q=vari%C3%A1dica&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5), [*variadica* em italiano (Wikipedia italiana)](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funzione_variadica) e [*variadique* em francês (Wiktionnaire)](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/variadique), o que dá credibilidade a *variádica*.

O Wiktionnaire observa que *variadique* foi formada segundo o modelo de *dyadique*, *monadique*, etc. Também *variádica* pode ser concebido como formado segundo o modelo de (ligações ao Priberam) [*diádico*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/di%C3%A1dico), relativo à [*díade*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/d%C3%ADade), ’grupo de dois’, [*triádico*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/tri%C3%A1dico), relativo a [*tríade*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/tr%C3%ADade), ’grupo de três’, etc. Com a diferença que nestes termos há o sufixo -*ico*, consagrado para formação de adjetivos em português (tal como -*ique* em francês, aliás), enquanto em *variádico* temos *vari(ável)* + -*ádico*, à semelhança de [*variadic* (Wiktionary)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/variadic), que explica que [-*adic*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-adic#English) foi formado regressivamente de *monadic*. Podemos inventar um *varíada* ’conjunto de número variável de elementos’, e fica a família completa :)

---

**Referências**

Livros

[Alan Donovan, Brian Kernigham, traduzido por Lúcia Kinoshita, *A Linguagem de Programação Go*, São Paulo, 2017.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Soh4DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT225&dq=vari%C3%A1dica&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXjZamnN_tAhUPQEEAHRDjA0YQ6AEwAHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=vari%C3%A1dica&f=false)

[Caleb Doxsey, traduzido por Lúcia Kinoshita, *Introdução à linguagem Go*, São Paulo, 2016.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=C_EhDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA101&dq=vari%C3%A1dica&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXjZamnN_tAhUPQEEAHRDjA0YQ6AEwAnoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=vari%C3%A1dica&f=false)

[David Flanagan, traduzido por João Eduardo Nóbrega Tortello, *Java Script, o guia definitivo*, 6ª edição, São Paulo, 2013.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=zWNyDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA168&dq=%22fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20vari%C3%A1dicas%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiwhtSTnd_tAhXCh1wKHf08A40Q6AEwAHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20vari%C3%A1dicas%22&f=false)

Dissertações

[João Guilherme Fritsche Colombo, *Máquinas de Turing não determinísticas com combinadora para a computação de funções*, Universidade Federal de Santa Catarina, Florianópolis, 2019.](https://repositorio.ufsc.br/bitstream/handle/123456789/202502/mtnc.pdf?sequence=5&isAllowed=y)

[Igor Silva e Rogério Silva, , “Linguagem de programação phyton”, *Revista Tecnologias em Projeção*, v. 10, nº 1, 2019.](http://revista.faculdadeprojecao.edu.br/index.php/Projecao4/article/view/1359)

[Antonio França da Guia, *O uso do AutoHotkey como Ferramenta de Automação em Ambiente Windows*, Universidade Federal do Estado do Rio de Janeiro, 2015.](https://www.uniriotec.br/%7Ebsi/tcc/textos/201512Franca.pdf)

[Augusto Henrique Vieira Dias, *Implementação para teste baseado em propriedade para linguagem Rust*, Universidade Federal de Ouro Preto, 2019.](https://d1wqtxts1xzle7.cloudfront.net/59952119/Mono20190707-111593-1dimu4g.pdf?1562525357=&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DAUGUSTO_HENRIQUE_VIEIRA_DIAS_IMPLEMENTAC.pdf&Expires=1608373109&Signature=a9iASrOvrliKruOi2hmG25jCNw6Nx5EjRLZecp6QymgI6Uzgrb%7EHtxF2C9iVQ347zOrDEAg8KXmQTuuPVSsK%7EI6fc3CU%7ErEPkv%7EXhIts2QHuW7pEpNCq0YV3jpNbQRQvXYtJCi6y64Si5X8a1pvsK76laEbETkuuRXDHi9FjeGs6dtynYi%7E2tB5Pj99B5qJr3uEuO92n1yR1R0QKJtKrcbwcVw4l7EDiNxEaE6sgp1gnST-fniFforrwzkw7aVgEYgaMegoWEAR1TgSv4y6qKVlQ5%7EHh%7EeBAec2epcFOXBrsmh9rCJWwbwiV3cZHcof1pKXjBOm3zQBrfnopyhbTUA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLOHF5GGSLRBV4ZA)

[Wilton de Melo Gonçalves Barbosa, *Elementos para a justificação de uma teoria contextualista da linguagem*, Universidade Federal de Pernambuco, Recife, 2013.](https://repositorio.ufpe.br/bitstream/123456789/10531/1/Disserta%C3%A7ao%20Wilton%20Barbosa%20ELEMENTOS%20PARA%20A%20JUSTIFICA%C3%87%C3%83O%20DE%20UMA%20TEORIA%20CONTEXTUALISTA%20DA%20LINGUAGEM.pdf)